# How to specify a newer version of wkhtmltopdf on CircleCI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit, circleci

I have a spec which tests generation of PDF with PDFKit. It uses the `wkhtmltopdf` command. I need to use the `--javascript-delay` option which is available in versions higher than 0.10.0. When my spec runs on CircleCI it fails, because CircleCI uses `wkhtltopdf` version 0.9.9. Can I specify a higher version of `wkhtmltopdf` on CircleCI? I specified the newest version of PDFKit in Gemfile, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 4):

Right now [Circle's test environment](https://circleci.com/docs/environment) is Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. So I went to http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html and found that the latest stable version of wkhtmltopdf is 0.12.2.1, and copied the download URL into the follow circle.yml configuration:

```
dependencies:
  pre:
    - sudo apt-get remove wkhtmltopdf
    - sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi
    - wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-precise-amd64.deb
    - sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-precise-amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 3):

[Yes, you can upgrade software on CircleCI build instances.](https://circleci.com/docs/installing-custom-software) You can either

- `apt-get install` the current package, if that's new enough (try it and watch the log to see what version you get) with something like this in circle.yml:

  ```
  dependencies:
    pre:
      - sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install some-package
  ```

or

- download the source, compile and install it with something like this in circle.yml:

  ```
  dependencies:
    pre:
      - wget http://example.com/some-package-2.0.0.tar.gz
      - tar xzf some-package-2.0.0.tar.gz
      - cd some-package-2.0.0 && make install
  ```

  If you need this solution, see the documentation I linked to above for how to cache the compiled software to speed up builds.

Answer (score 1):

A really, really convenient solution is to simply drop in the gem [wkhtmltopdf-heroku](https://rubygems.org/gems/wkhtmltopdf-heroku/versions/2.12.2.1). While the name of the gem says heroku, I found that it works just fine in Circle, too. As a bonus, I believe this dependency will be cached between builds without any special instructions to Circle.